# Why I am getting a filter error for my template tag?

Tags: django

I'm not sure why I am getting this filter error. I looked up other peoples similar issues with this, and I am definitely loading my template tag, I restarted the server, I have a template tags folder with an **init**.py file and the file that holds my tag, so , what am I doing wrong here?

error is at `{{ request.user|unread_messages }}`, **Invalid filter: 'unread_messages'**

**unread_message_counter.py**

```
from django import template
from dating_app import models 

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def unread_messages(user):
    return user.InstantMessage.filter(viewed=False).count()
```

**base.htmnl **

```
{% load bootstrap4 %}

{% load unread_messages_counter %}


<!-- Navbar is located in this file -->


<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    {% block head %}
    <title>Basee</title>
    {% endblock %}
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">

        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault" aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'dating_app:home' %}">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>



            </ul>
            <!-- Below is login/registration links and the logic-->
            {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                Hello, {{  user.username  }}
                <ul class="mylinks">
                  <div>
                    <li><a href="{% url 'dating_app:profile' user.id %}">My Profile</a></li>
                    <li><a href="{% url 'dating_app:logout' %}">log out</a></li>
                  <div>
                </ul>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'dating_app:view_matches' user.id %}">Matches</a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'dating_app:conversations' user.id %}">Inbox</a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'dating_app:mingle' %}">Mingle</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    {{ request.user|unread_messages }}
                </li>




            {% else %}
              <div>
                <a href="{% url 'dating_app:login' %}">log in</a>
                <br>
                <a href="{% url 'dating_app:register' %}">register</a>
              </div>
            {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is *not* a [*template tag* [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/language/#tags), this is a [*template filter* [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/language/#filters). A tag would mean you render this as `{% unread_messages … %}`. You thus can make it a filter with:

```
from django import template
from dating_app import models 

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def unread_messages(user):
    return user.InstantMessage.filter(viewed=False).count()
```

Or you can work with a *tag*, by keeping the `@registered.simple_tag`, and render this with `{% unread_messages request.user %}`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is the name used to load the tag.

Instead of:

```
{% load unread_messages_counter %}
```

Try:

```
{% load unread_messages %}
```